# automatic call forwarding - accessing the rodent's large intestine

Tags: dart

D language has 'alias ...'. Go has embedded fields. Does Dart have a way, in the code below, to get to the Rodent's large intestine, without going through the guts? Ideally some way of exposing an aggregate of internals, en masse without having to create forwarding calls in each animal with some common set of internals?

```dart
import 'dart:io';

class Stomach {
  work() { print("stomach"); }
}
class LargeIntestine {
  work() { print("large intestine"); }
}
class SmallIntestine {
  work() { print("small intestine"); }
}

class Guts {
  Stomach stomach = new Stomach();
  LargeIntestine largeIntestine = new LargeIntestine();
  SmallIntestine smallIntestine = new SmallIntestine();
  work() {
    stomach.work(); 
    largeIntestine.work();
    smallIntestine.work();
  }
}

class Rodent {
  Guts guts = new Guts();
  work() => guts.work();
}

main() {
  Rodent rodent = new Rodent();
  rodent.guts.largeIntestine;
  rodent.work();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate your interest in... biology, and am happy to say that the construct you're looking for is probably the `get` keyword.

See: http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#classes-getters-and-setters

```dart
class Rodent {
  Guts guts = new Guts();
  work() => guts.work();

  // Getter for the Rodent's large intestine.
  LargeIntestine get largeIntestine => guts.largeIntestine;
}

main() {
  Rodent rodent = new Rodent();

  // Use the getter.
  rodent.largeIntestine;
  rodent.work();

  rodent.awake();
  rodent.recognizeMaster();
  if (rodent.self.awareness && rodent.self.isMonster) {
    rodent.turn.on(rodent.master);
    print("Oh. Oh, no! NoOooOO! Argghhhhhh...");
    rodent.largeIntestine.work();
  }
}
```

---

Or, if you're looking to save writing work, you could have a super class or interface or mixin (depending on what you want to do) that has the properties you're looking for:

```dart
class Animal {
  LargeIntestine largeIntestine = new LargeIntestine();
  ...
}

class Rodent extends Animal { ... }
```

or

```dart
class Rodent extends Object with Animal { ... }
```

See: http://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm looking for less work than declaring 'get' for each organ in each animal. For instance, with D you can do 'alias this guts' in Rodent and then you get to use members of guts directly from the Rodent. So, this is a toy example, but assume there will be 30 animals and I don't want 30*3 copy/paste getters (i.e. without copy/paste forwarding). I've not yet used mixins in Dart - so maybe that has a potential solution?